# Flair: Missing Profile Picture in dark theme

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I awant to use the **dark theme** in my flair. However, when I am changing the **default** theme to **dark** using `?theme=dark` the profile picture on the flair goes missing.

What could be causing this and how do I overcome this to use the dark theme?

Please find the below screenshot:

[image]

**NOTE:** This is not the case with other themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce this error:

[image]

Try with different browsers, and also check the browsers javascript console for any errors to narrow down the issue

Comment: It is working fine in Mozilla and IE. But not in Chrome. In chrome it is giving the following error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeQMW.jpg?s=64&g=1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`

Comment: I tried in Chrome successfully. Have you tried to open an incognito window and login to your account there and then try that way? (To rule out the session it self)

Comment: yes.... even in incognito it is showing the same behavior

Comment: I don't know what was wrong yesterday... But today, even in Chrome it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Could have been a problem on the imgur-side probably